# Email sending Issues using asp.net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I sending email i got this issues

> "Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.1.0 ..
>   temporary failure".

How to solve this error?

Comment: Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: im using     <add key="Email.HostAddress" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="Email.Port" value="587"/>

Comment: Hi Deva, welcome to Stackoverflow! Here are some help pages to get you started: [Asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Questions without a [clear problem statement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are not useful to other readers; see if you can be more specific with your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen in following case:

1. The exchange server is out of disk space.
2. The recipient mailbox is out of disk space.

It is more common to run into issue #2 than issue #1. This question is already answer, see the below link

[System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Insufficient system storage. The server response was: 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692376/system-net-mail-smtpexception-insufficient-system-storage-the-server-response)

Comment: Thank you so much Totalo Doto Neto